# Ajax not loading with reverse proxy on apache2 with raspberry

Tags: ajax, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm using apache 2 with reverse proxy configuration. While the websites from the the internal servers (192.168.x.x) are in priniciple loading correctly when accessed through the internet, the ajax script on the servers is not, at least it's not displayed on the website (the rest is). I'm maximally confused, how to overcome this?

When I access the the website from the intneral network, that is the the internet website and NOT the proxy website on the internal server, the ajax script is also not working. the script is only working, when i'm accessing the proxy server's website from the intneral network directly.